# Calculate the taylor polynomial $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2)log(1-z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been given the following question that I need help with. I have calculated grad f but I'm just not sure exactly how to calculate the taylor polynomial which is part c.

Consider the function $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2)\log(1-z)$

a) Find the maximal domain, which I found to be $$\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:z<1\}$$

b) Find $\nabla f$. I found this to be
$$\nabla f=(2x\log(1-z), 2y\log(1-z), \frac{x^2+y^2}{z-1})$$

c) Find $T^1_{(2,2,0)}f(x,y,z)$

Comment: the third coordinate of $\nabla f$ might benefit from checking

Comment: oh thank you, didn't pick up on that one. How would I go about finding the first order taylor polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general
$$
f(\bar r) = f(\bar r_0) + \nabla f_{\bar r_0} \cdot (\bar r -\bar r_0) + \cdots\
$$
here $\bar r_0$ is the point $(2,2,0)$ so $\bar r - \bar r_0$ is $(x-2,y-2,z)$. compute the values of $f(\bar r_0)$ and $\nabla f_{\bar r_0}$ and you have what you need